# famous for "its"... or famous for without "its"

Tags: indefinite-article, possessives, determiners, confusable

> 1. Madura is famous for **its** heart-stopping bull race, filled with excitement.
> 2. Madura is famous for **a** heart-stopping bull race, filled with excitement.

Could you please tell me the difference of with "its" and without "its" in these two sentences?

Comment: *its* is the possessive for *it.*

Answer (score 1):

"its" is possessive.

"a" is the indefinite article.  States that it is an unspecified one of many.

> Madura is famous for its heart-stopping bull race

Madura is famous for the heart-stopping bull-race which belongs to Madura.  (or, by extension, closely-coupled with Madura)

> Madura is famous for a heart-stopping bull race

There are many heart-stopping bull-races.  Madura is famous for one of them.